# Problems with installing python tools for visual studio 2010

Tags: python, wpf, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, ptvs

I installed [iron python 2.7.3](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/81726)
and [python tools for visual studio 1.1](http://pytools.codeplex.com/releases/view/76091)

but when i try to create a new python project it only offers me to create a command-line application.
I wanted to create a GUI with iron Python so i was looking forward to create a WPF project. The documentation states that it should be available if I installed iron python. Did I do anything wrong? I tried reinstalling both iron python and python tools.

Comment: Does something simple as restarting visual studio anything good?

Comment: no I tried restarting and reinstalling already

Comment: Did you have that opportunity before the installation? Are you using a Express version of visual studio?

Comment: I don't understand your first question, but no I use the professional version.

Comment: Did you have the opportunity to create a WPF project before the python installation?

Comment: i can still create wpfs for c# just not for python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing it. Did you setup the interactive and interpreter settings to use your ironpython 2.7.3?

Step "3. Getting PTVS": http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation%20-%20details&referringTitle=Home

You should see your IronPython 2.7.3 version on the dropdown list on both screens under Tools > Options > Python Tools

[image]

[image]

And, for me, it worked, all templates are available:

[image]

UPDATE: Look for the templates folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\IronPython Interpreter\1.5\Templates\Projects

You should have: 
- ConsoleProject
- SilverlightProject
- WinformsProject
- WpfProject

You may have a problem with the templates, so look at this website and find out exactly how project templates work and where are all located so you can try to fix them yourself (if the problem persists).

Visual Studio Templates

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6db0hwky(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: no interpreter was automatically added, i had to add one for iron python myself. The only difference I see is that i installed python under C:\Programms but that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: you may have a problem with the project templates. try to find where they were installed and you can confirm if they all are there. See my update.

Comment: ok I tried uninstalling and reinstalling python tools, visual studio and iron python(this time its on C:\), which didn't help.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft has no IronPythonInterpreter folder only PythonProfiler and PythonTools. Is there a way to get that folder directly?

Comment: also is there a possible reason that the ironpython interpreter isn't added automatically? I have the fear that it won't work when i manually add it.

Comment: I confirm that the python project templates come from: ..\IronPython Interpreter\1.5\Templates\Projects . I manually changed the name of the WpfProject to WpfProject___X and the template is no more available in VS New Projects > Python... so, if u dont have IronPythonInterpreter folder that's the reason u dont see them.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the main problem, though I think the reason this folder wasn't created is the same reason the ironpython interpreter wasn't added. VS can't find Iron python for some reason. Could it be that the newest Version isn't compatible with VS 2010?

Comment: i dont think so. I just installed ip2.7.3 with vs2010 and it worked just fine. in fact i did a diff step. I had VS2010 already installed and also Python3.3 64bit (the CPython) I installed PVST1.5 and everything worked fine. The setup automatically selected CPython33 as interpreter and the project templates where available. then i installed IP2.7.3 and I changed the settings to use that instead of CPython. try installing CPython then PTVS

Comment: I don't know why and I don't even want to think about it, but that did the trick, thanks alot